# How to enforce Entity Manager to use @SqlResultSetMapping and @NamedNativeQuery for fetching data?

Tags: java, mysql, entity-framework, jpa, eclipselink

I have entity class "Geo" to store geospatial data which uses @SqlResultSetMapping and @NamedNativeQuery (on database I use binary data that are represented by WKT String in entity). Everything works perfect if i use stateless beans with facade methods calling  NamedNativeQueries and when I work ONLY with Geo objects.

My problem occurrs when I use Geo objects in related classes. I have entity class 'Location' related to Geo (according to tables  in db), where i have joined column:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "GEOGUID")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Geo geoguid;
```

The geoguid object is always constructed by  standard EnityManager method:
  T  find(java.lang.Class entityClass, java.lang.Object primaryKey).

Is there any possibility to annotate field/column in a way that EM will perform a defined native Query to get Geo?
Maybe, there is another  way to convert single column data in my situation?
I was considering:
- implicit cast on db i.e. geometry->varchar,
- using @Converter implementing AttributeConverter

but from different reasons I could not use them.

Geo is class annotated with @Entity containing  field coordinates as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "geo")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({....
@NamedNativeQueries({...
@SqlResultSetMappings({...
... 
public class Geo implements Serializable
...//other fields
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "coordinates")
private String coordinates;
...
```

corresponding to binary data (of 'Point' type in MariaDB) in db table. I have mappings as described above and everything goes ok when I don't need fetching data by entity manager. I can create/update geo with my own nativequeries and the same with find, findAll and so on. All records in DB are correct. The problem appears when using joincolumn in other entity classes because geo instances are fetched then by EM standard find function and coordinates are not converted  correctly (they are still strings but like '000000xccvbfrfrdd00000' instead of WKT 'POINT(10 10)'). 
The whole mapping is just 'astext(coords)' and i tried to put it into columndefinition, columnreferencedname etc. but no result.

How can I provide converted 'coordinates' field to other classes using ManyToOne or other relations? May i enforce EM to convert it somehow?

Comment: where is this "Geo" entity? In JPA you do not define random native queries to retrieve something or other.

Comment: What is different from your ResultSetMapping that isn't in your entity?  They need to be similar if you want to be able to use JPA methods on your entity.  Otherwise, you can specify the query to use on this particular mapping, or every time the GEO entity is read in, but you'll have to go indepth into the documentation to learn the native api to do what you want with descriptor customizers.